# Removing badge from button in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2.2

How can I remove the button badge based on condition like if badgetext is less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Hi u can get the badgetext value using `var badge  = getBadgeText( );` it will return a string check if its equal to 0 if condition true hide it as simple as that...

Answer (score 0):

Though it is an old one, I found this question while searching for the answer to similar problem. I sorted it out like :

```
        switch(myStore.getCount()){           
            case 0:
                view.down('#someButton').setBadgeText('');
                break;
            case 1:
                view.down('#someButton').setBadgeText('1 Image');
                break;
            default:
                view.down('#someButton').setBadgeText(myStore.getCount() + ' Images');
        }
```

So I guess, just using the view.down('#someButton').getBadgeText() and comparing it to length you desire can be done.